# explaination of $logline{$cod}{s1} = scalar keys %{$valid{$cod}};

Tags: perl

What does the following perl code aim to do?

```
$logline{$cod}{s1} = scalar keys %{$valid{$cod}};
```

"valid" should be treated as a hashref, and $cod should be treated as a key. Is that right?

what does "s1" in the left hand stand for, a key again?

Comment: by the way, the `scalar` is entirely superfluous. The expression is already in scalar context.

Comment: Please read [perldoc perldata](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html) and [perldoc perlref](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlref.html) and all will be much clearer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## RHS

Get the value of `%valid` indexed by `$cod`.

```
$valid{$cod}
```

Treat that value as if it were a hashref.

```
%{$valid{$cod}}
```

Get a list of keys of that hashref.

```
keys %{$valid{$cod}}
```

Find out how many keys are in that list.

```
scalar keys %{$valid{$cod}}
```

(This is not how it actually works, instead [`keys`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/keys.html) called in scalar context returns a number representing how many elements it would have returned had it been in list context.)

---

## LHS

The hash `%logline` is indexed by `$cod`.

```
$logline{$cod}
```

Which is itself a hashref, which is indexed by `s1`.

```
$logline{$cod}{s1}
```

---

## Bring it all together

The value of the first segment is stored at the position indicated by the second

```
$logline{$cod}{s1} = scalar keys %{$valid{$cod}};
```

Comment: @ikegami I couldn't think of a way to put it without writing it different than the original. Or writing something that was difficult to write, let alone read. Perhaps I should just break it up more, even if it will have to be written differently.

Comment: Can you even use `scalar` on a list? In perldoc it says that when used on a parenthesized list, it returns only the last element. On an array, yes, but not on a list.

Comment: I was indicating what `keys` is useful for in list context, as well as in scalar context.

Comment: @TLP, Re: "Can you even use scalar on a list?", it depends on what you mean by "list". It's impossible to pass a list value to `scalar` since `scalar` prevents it from getting created, but you can use `scalar` on a list/comma op (e.g. `scalar(x(),y(),z())` is similar to `do { x(); y(); z() }`.)

Comment: @Brad Gilbert, awesome. Comment retracted.

Answer (score 2):

It stores the number of elements in the hashref referenced by $valid{$cod} into the LHS.

```
"valid" should be treated as a hashref,
```

No, "valid" is the name of the %valid hash and $valid{} accesses one of the values in the hash.

$cod is a hash key in both places. "s1" is a hash key also.

Comment: so $logline{$cod} is hashref again, and s1 is a key for this second level hash? Is my understanding right?

Comment: @user1109094, `s1` is a bareword that produces the string `s1`, and yes, it's used as the key for the hash referenced by `$logline{$cod}`.